# Windows Server 2016 cannot connect to WSUS server

Tags: wsus

I have a brand new installation of Windows Server 2016 WSUS server (Fully patched until 18-Dec-2016). My network consists of about 1000 client-side operating systems and 300 server-side. The clients range from Windows 7 to Windows 10 version 1607. The servers are from Windows Server 2008 to Windows Server 2016. Every computer can connect to WSUS and pull the updates except for Windows Server 2016.

Each time I check for updates on a Windows Server 2016, I get this error: "We couldn't connect to the update service. We'll try again later, or you can check now. If it still doesn't work, make sure you're connected to the Internet."

Event Viewer: Windows Update failed to check for updates with error 0x80072EFD.

The strange thing is, WSUS server puts a green check mark for Windows Server 2016s, but I am sure there are some updates available for them.

I have installed all the Cumulative Updates (CUs) so far available for Windows Server 2016 on one of my 2016 installations manually, to see if that would solve the problem, but it didn’t. 
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a manifestation of "[Windows Update stuck at 0 percent on Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4039473/windows-update-stuck-at-0-percent-on-windows-10-and-windows-server-201)". There are a few different ways to get stuck in this problem but one of them is still being on the original RTM version (10.0.14393.0) of the Windows Update Agent and trying to use a WSUS server...

Answer (score -1):

First try to run the windows update troubleshooter there might be an update that failed to download / install and its hanging there .

Next open a command prompt and type wuauclt /detectnow
It will allow the computer to detect your wsus immediately if not .

Make sure firewall is turned off and your wsus is reachable and pingable .

If problem persists in worst case scenarios i suggest you deploy your wsus on the GPO by ip address and not hostname .

Comment: It is very seldom a good idea to recommend disabling a firewall.

Comment: if its a part of a domain its not that bad you can enhance security features and access list controls on it beside most companies that run a domain have a firewall besides the windows one .

Comment: At a minimum you should include any of those qualifications in the answer. Regardless, it still isn't good advice!

Answer (score -1):

Remove WSUS Settings via PowerShell

- Click Start and open PowerShell as Administrator (`Right Click > Run as Administrator`)
- Stop the Windows Update Service by entering the command `Stop-Service -Name wuauserv`
- Remove the Windows Update registry key by entering the command `Remove-Item HKLM: \Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate -Recurse`
- Finally, Start the Windows Update Service again by entering the command `Start-Service -name wuauserv`

Comment: That is not a solution. That undos all the OPs work. E.g group policy settings. And suddenly all clients are going to Microsoft directly for updates which for a network his size isn’t going to be the best idea.