# WSUS Windows 10 Updates not working

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus, windows-update, windows-10

I know this is a well known issue, but I've tried everything I can find online and I still can't get 1607 or 1703 to deploy to my Windows 10 clients using WSUS on Server 2012 R2. Originally I synchronised WSUS without installing KB3159706 which meant that none of my downloaded updates had been decrypted. I eventually ended up uninstalling WSUS and deleting it's directories and database to start again fresh.

I installed KB3159706 and HTTP Activation for .Net 4.5 and then installed and configured WSUS. I then tried deploying 1607 but kept getting "Download Failed" errors. At this point I deleted the SoftwareDistribution and CatRoot2 folders and tried again to no avail. Next I discovered and added the '.esd - application/octet-stream' MIME type to IIS and tried deploying to a couple of different Win 10 PC's, but still couldn't get it to work.

I have run the following query taken from this Microsoft article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3194588/-0xc1800118-error-when-you-push-windows-10-version-1607-by-using-wsus

```
select TotalResults = Count(*)
from tbFile
where (IsEncrypted = 1 and DecryptionKey is NULL) or (FileName like '%14393%.esd' and IsEncrypted = 0)
```

The result I got was '0' which according to the article means my database is correct and my updates can be decrypted.

I have some PC's which had been imaged originally with 1607, so I have now tried deploying 1703 to those PC's and they don't work either. I also tried skipping 1607 by deploying 1703 to a PC running 1511.

At the moment I am getting error: 0x8024200D (The update handler did not install the update because it needs to be downloaded again) - Error description taken from https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/938205/windows-update-error-code-list.

Here is the Windows Update log from a PC after trying to install 1703:

```
2017/05/14 13:51:28.8879116 852   3544  ComApi          *QUEUED* Download ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
2017/05/14 13:51:28.8879182 852   2916  Agent           Obtained a network PDC reference for callID {A1D6AFB9-7784-42E7-91A2-1A2906FB843B} with No-Progress-Timeout set to 4294967295; ActivationID: 25.
2017/05/14 13:51:28.8911111 852   2916  DownloadManager * START * Begin Downloading Updates [CallerId = UpdateOrchestrator] [Call ID = A1D6AFB9-7784-42E7-91A2-1A2906FB843B]
2017/05/14 13:51:28.8911145 852   2916  DownloadManager Priority = 2, NetworkCostPolicy = 0, Interactive = 0, Download on Battery = 0, Bypass Regulation = 0, Owner is system = 1, Proxy session id = -1, ServiceId = 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7
2017/05/14 13:51:28.8911153 852   2916  DownloadManager Updates to download = 1
2017/05/14 13:51:28.8911157 852   2916  Agent             Title = Feature update to Windows 10 Education, version 1703, en-us
2017/05/14 13:51:28.8911188 852   2916  Agent             UpdateId = 6C9BC0F9-0912-488D-AE71-85431F407F09.201
2017/05/14 13:51:28.8911192 852   2916  Agent               Bundles 1 updates:
2017/05/14 13:51:28.8911222 852   2916  Agent                 CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790.201
2017/05/14 13:51:28.8911619 852   2916  DownloadManager No locked revisions found for update 6C9BC0F9-0912-488D-AE71-85431F407F09; locking the user-specified revision.
2017/05/14 13:51:28.9492355 852   2916  DownloadManager No locked revisions found for update CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790; locking the user-specified revision.
2017/05/14 13:51:28.9718986 852   2916  DownloadManager Regulation: {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} - Loaded sequence number 65535 for regulation category PerUpdate.
2017/05/14 13:51:28.9718994 852   2916  DownloadManager Regulation: {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} - Loaded sequence number 65535 for regulation category Low.
2017/05/14 13:51:28.9719002 852   2916  DownloadManager Regulation: {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} - Loaded sequence number 65535 for regulation category Normal.
2017/05/14 13:51:28.9719005 852   2916  DownloadManager Regulation: {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} - Loaded sequence number 65535 for regulation category High.
2017/05/14 13:51:29.0460875 852   2916  Handler         Loaded state. m_dwState now: <invalid>(0)
2017/05/14 13:51:29.0571159 852   2916  DownloadManager Update CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790.201 is missing decryption information
2017/05/14 13:51:29.0571190 852   2916  DownloadManager Update CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790.201 is missing decryption information
2017/05/14 13:51:29.0576622 852   2916  DownloadManager DynamicDownloadDataFetcher: {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} - added new entry for Update {CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790}.201
2017/05/14 13:51:29.1209793 852   2916  DownloadManager Queueing update {CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790}.201 for download handler request generation.
2017/05/14 13:51:29.1223140 852   2916  Handler         Loaded state. m_dwState now: <invalid>(0)
2017/05/14 13:51:29.1701210 852   2916  Shared          Effective power state: AC
2017/05/14 13:51:29.1701249 852   2916  Agent           Released network PDC reference for callId {A1D6AFB9-7784-42E7-91A2-1A2906FB843B}; ActivationID: 25
2017/05/14 13:51:29.1701337 852   2916  Agent           Obtained a network PDC reference for callID {A1D6AFB9-7784-42E7-91A2-1A2906FB843B} with No-Progress-Timeout set to 4294967295; ActivationID: 26.
2017/05/14 13:51:29.1703639 852   4028  Agent           WU client calls back to download call {A1D6AFB9-7784-42E7-91A2-1A2906FB843B} with code Call progress and error 0
2017/05/14 13:51:29.1705529 852   2992  Handler         Loaded state. m_dwState now: <invalid>(0)
2017/05/14 13:51:29.1705749 852   2992  DownloadManager Generating download request for update {CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790}.201
2017/05/14 13:51:29.1712713 852   2992  DownloadManager Calling into handler 0xa to generate download request for update CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790.201
2017/05/14 13:51:29.1715284 852   2992  Handler         Loaded state. m_dwState now: <invalid>(0)
2017/05/14 13:51:29.1715592 852   2992  Handler         Windows Setup handler requesting installer file 'WindowsUpdateBox.exe'
2017/05/14 13:51:29.1715696 852   2992  Handler         State changed. was: <invalid>(0), now: Setup360_Phase1DownloadRequest(3)
2017/05/14 13:51:29.1721544 852   2992  Handler         Saved state. m_dwState: Setup360_Phase1DownloadRequest(3)
2017/05/14 13:51:29.2185324 852   2916  Shared          Effective power state: AC
2017/05/14 13:51:29.2185386 852   2916  Agent           Released network PDC reference for callId {A1D6AFB9-7784-42E7-91A2-1A2906FB843B}; ActivationID: 26
2017/05/14 13:51:29.2185470 852   2916  Agent           Obtained a network PDC reference for callID {A1D6AFB9-7784-42E7-91A2-1A2906FB843B} with No-Progress-Timeout set to 4294967295; ActivationID: 27.
2017/05/14 13:51:29.2185501 852   2916  DownloadManager * END * Begin Downloading Updates CallerId = UpdateOrchestrator
2017/05/14 13:51:29.2187518 852   4028  Agent           WU client calls back to download call {A1D6AFB9-7784-42E7-91A2-1A2906FB843B} with code Call progress and error 0
2017/05/14 13:51:29.2190329 852   2916  DownloadManager DynamicDownloadDataFetcher Refresh Svc: {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}
2017/05/14 13:51:29.2190440 852   2916  DownloadManager Fetching dynamic data from service 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7 for 1 updates.
2017/05/14 13:51:29.2190706 852   2916  Misc            Got WSUS SecuredClient/Server URL: http://servername:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx/secured""
2017/05/14 13:51:29.2190979 852   2916  WebServices     Auto proxy settings for this web service call.
2017/05/14 13:51:29.2671567 852   2916  DownloadManager GetExtendedUpdateInfo2 returned, hr=0x00000000, FileLocations=2, FileDecryptionData=2
2017/05/14 13:51:29.3250743 852   2916  DownloadManager DynamicDownloadDataFetcher Refresh complete. 0x00000000
2017/05/14 13:51:29.3250894 852   2916  DownloadManager DynamicDownloadDataFetcher Refreshed Update {CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790} SetDynamicResult: 0
2017/05/14 13:51:29.3250897 852   2916  DownloadManager DynamicDownloadDataFetcher HandleDynamicDataRefreshResult HR(0x00000000)
2017/05/14 13:51:32.5878311 852   2916  DownloadManager DO job initialized, JobId = {AADB3662-196D-4C1D-BA94-FCBFEF9C5EBE}
2017/05/14 13:51:32.6090834 852   2916  DownloadManager Downloading from http://servername:8530/Content/C9/A9186BC92CFDACE903B62AB20E6A7F0FCDB533C9.exe to C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\31dde1e25bcbfe972aa2306200d63ffb\WindowsUpdateBox.exe (full file).
2017/05/14 13:51:32.6092027 852   2916  Handler         Loaded state. m_dwState now: Setup360_Phase1DownloadRequest(3)
2017/05/14 13:51:32.6338581 852   2916  DownloadManager New download job {AADB3662-196D-4C1D-BA94-FCBFEF9C5EBE} for UpdateId CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790.201
2017/05/14 13:51:32.8269682 852   2916  DownloadManager Download job AADB3662-196D-4C1D-BA94-FCBFEF9C5EBE resumed.
2017/05/14 13:51:32.8272873 852   2916  Handler         Loaded state. m_dwState now: Setup360_Phase1DownloadRequest(3)
2017/05/14 13:51:32.8292906 852   2916  Shared          Effective power state: AC
2017/05/14 13:51:32.8292983 852   2916  Agent           Released network PDC reference for callId {A1D6AFB9-7784-42E7-91A2-1A2906FB843B}; ActivationID: 27
2017/05/14 13:51:32.8293053 852   2916  Agent           Obtained a network PDC reference for callID {A1D6AFB9-7784-42E7-91A2-1A2906FB843B} with No-Progress-Timeout set to 4294967295; ActivationID: 29.
2017/05/14 13:51:32.8296075 852   4028  Agent           WU client calls back to download call {A1D6AFB9-7784-42E7-91A2-1A2906FB843B} with code Call progress and error 0
2017/05/14 13:51:32.8397716 852   2916  DownloadManager Download job AADB3662-196D-4C1D-BA94-FCBFEF9C5EBE resumed.
2017/05/14 13:51:32.8400615 852   2916  Handler         Loaded state. m_dwState now: Setup360_Phase1DownloadRequest(3)
2017/05/14 13:51:32.8515665 852   2916  DownloadManager Download job AADB3662-196D-4C1D-BA94-FCBFEF9C5EBE resumed.
2017/05/14 13:51:32.8519592 852   2916  Handler         Loaded state. m_dwState now: Setup360_Phase1DownloadRequest(3)
2017/05/14 13:51:35.6973300 852   4120  DownloadManager DO job {AADB3662-196D-4C1D-BA94-FCBFEF9C5EBE} completed successfully
2017/05/14 13:51:35.7608812 852   4120  Handler         Loaded state. m_dwState now: Setup360_Phase1DownloadRequest(3)
2017/05/14 13:51:35.9501590 852   4120  Misc            Validating signature for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\31dde1e25bcbfe972aa2306200d63ffb\WindowsUpdateBox.exe with dwProvFlags 0x00000080:
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4282001 852   4120  Misc             Microsoft signed: Yes
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4282686 852   4120  Handler         State changed. was: Setup360_Phase1DownloadRequest(3), now: Setup360_Phase1DownloadComplete(4)
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4286856 852   4120  Handler         Saved state. m_dwState: Setup360_Phase1DownloadComplete(4)
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4291714 852   4120  DownloadManager   Download job completion. Progress for update {CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790} - total = 19989072, transferred = 19989072 bytes. Transfer time=2497, connect time=0 (ms)
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4561134 852   2916  DownloadManager Update CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790.201 is missing decryption information
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4565846 852   2916  DownloadManager DynamicDownloadDataFetcher: {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} - added new entry for Update {CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790}.201
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4672242 852   2916  DownloadManager Queueing update {CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790}.201 for download handler request generation.
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4680422 852   2992  Handler         Loaded state. m_dwState now: Setup360_Phase1DownloadComplete(4)
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4680919 852   2992  DownloadManager Generating download request for update {CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790}.201
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4682382 852   2992  DownloadManager Calling into handler 0xa to generate download request for update CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790.201
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4685258 852   2992  Handler         Loaded state. m_dwState now: Setup360_Phase1DownloadComplete(4)
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4685589 852   2992  Handler         State changed. was: Setup360_Phase1DownloadComplete(4), now: Setup360_CompatToolPhase1(5)
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4689511 852   2992  Handler         Saved state. m_dwState: Setup360_CompatToolPhase1(5)
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4755710 852   2916  Shared          Effective power state: AC
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4755764 852   2916  Agent           Released network PDC reference for callId {A1D6AFB9-7784-42E7-91A2-1A2906FB843B}; ActivationID: 29
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4755829 852   2916  Agent           Obtained a network PDC reference for callID {A1D6AFB9-7784-42E7-91A2-1A2906FB843B} with No-Progress-Timeout set to 4294967295; ActivationID: 30.
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4757969 852   4028  Agent           WU client calls back to download call {A1D6AFB9-7784-42E7-91A2-1A2906FB843B} with code Call progress and error 0
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4760372 852   2916  DownloadManager DynamicDownloadDataFetcher Refresh Svc: {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4760479 852   2916  DownloadManager Fetching dynamic data from service 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7 for 1 updates.
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4760722 852   2916  Misc            Got WSUS SecuredClient/Server URL: http://servername:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx/secured""
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4760887 852   2916  WebServices     Auto proxy settings for this web service call.
2017/05/14 13:51:37.4846468 852   2916  DownloadManager GetExtendedUpdateInfo2 returned, hr=0x00000000, FileLocations=2, FileDecryptionData=2
2017/05/14 13:51:37.5112347 852   2916  DownloadManager DynamicDownloadDataFetcher Refresh complete. 0x00000000
2017/05/14 13:51:37.5112486 852   2916  DownloadManager DynamicDownloadDataFetcher Refreshed Update {CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790} SetDynamicResult: 0
2017/05/14 13:51:37.5112493 852   2916  DownloadManager DynamicDownloadDataFetcher HandleDynamicDataRefreshResult HR(0x00000000)
2017/05/14 13:51:37.5370580 852   2916  DownloadManager All files for update {CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790}.201 were already downloaded and are valid.
2017/05/14 13:51:37.5750862 852   2916  Handler         Loaded state. m_dwState now: Setup360_CompatToolPhase1(5)
2017/05/14 13:51:37.6326046 852   2916  DownloadManager * END * Download Call Complete Call 2 for caller UpdateOrchestrator has completed; signaling completion.
2017/05/14 13:51:37.7184340 852   2916  Shared          Effective power state: AC
2017/05/14 13:51:37.7184383 852   2916  Agent           Released network PDC reference for callId {A1D6AFB9-7784-42E7-91A2-1A2906FB843B}; ActivationID: 30
2017/05/14 13:51:37.7186569 852   4028  ComApi          *RESUMED* Download ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
2017/05/14 13:51:37.7186592 852   4028  ComApi          Download call complete (succeeded = 1, succeeded with errors = 0, failed = 0, unaccounted = 0)
2017/05/14 13:51:37.7186619 852   4028  ComApi          * END *   Download ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
2017/05/14 13:51:37.7186639 852   4028  Agent           WU client calls back to download call {A1D6AFB9-7784-42E7-91A2-1A2906FB843B} with code Call complete and error 0
2017/05/14 13:51:37.7190350 852   3544  ComApi          ISusInternal:: DisconnectCall failed, hr=8024000C
2017/05/14 13:51:37.7805501 852   2916  DownloadManager DynamicDownloadDataFetcher Refresh Svc: {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}
2017/05/14 13:51:37.7805532 852   2916  DownloadManager DynamicDownloadDataFetcher Refresh complete. 0x8024000c
2017/05/14 13:51:37.9479974 852   3544  DownloadManager MapToLockedRevision for updateId = {6C9BC0F9-0912-488D-AE71-85431F407F09}.201 failed with 0x80240008
2017/05/14 13:51:37.9482280 852   3544  Handler         Loaded state. m_dwState now: Setup360_CompatToolPhase1(5)
2017/05/14 13:51:38.3858839 852   3544  ComApi          * START *   Install ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
2017/05/14 13:51:38.3858850 852   3544  ComApi          Allow source prompts: Yes; Forced: No; Force quiet: No; Attempt close apps if necessary: No
2017/05/14 13:51:38.3859027 852   3544  ComApi          Updates in request: 1
2017/05/14 13:51:38.3859120 852   3544  ComApi          ServiceID = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} Managed
2017/05/14 13:51:38.3865279 852   3544  Agent           Beginning install of conventional work item
2017/05/14 13:51:38.3865460 852   3544  ComApi          *QUEUED* Updates to install = 1
2017/05/14 13:51:38.3865468 852   3544  ComApi          Install ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
2017/05/14 13:51:38.3868686 852   4336  Agent           *  START  *  Installing updates CallerId = UpdateOrchestrator
2017/05/14 13:51:38.3868694 852   4336  Agent           Updates to install = 1
2017/05/14 13:51:38.3897454 852   4336  Agent             Title = Feature update to Windows 10 Education, version 1703, en-us
2017/05/14 13:51:38.3897508 852   4336  Agent             UpdateId = 6C9BC0F9-0912-488D-AE71-85431F407F09.201
2017/05/14 13:51:38.3897512 852   4336  Agent               Bundles 1 updates:
2017/05/14 13:51:38.3897543 852   4336  Agent                 CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790.201
2017/05/14 13:51:38.8001401 852   4336  Handler         Loaded state. m_dwState now: Setup360_CompatToolPhase1(5)
2017/05/14 13:51:38.8442553 852   2916  Misc            Got WSUS Client/Server URL: http://servername:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx""
2017/05/14 13:51:38.8443138 852   2916  ProtocolTalker  OK to reuse existing configuration
2017/05/14 13:51:38.8443173 852   2916  ProtocolTalker  Existing cookie is valid, just use it
2017/05/14 13:51:38.8443181 852   2916  ProtocolTalker  PTInfo: Server requested registration
2017/05/14 13:51:38.8547244 852   2916  Misc            Got WSUS Reporting URL: http://servername:8530/ReportingWebService/ReportingWebService.asmx""
2017/05/14 13:51:38.8548572 852   2916  WebServices     Auto proxy settings for this web service call.
2017/05/14 13:51:38.9721092 852   4336  DownloadManager Preparing update for install, updateId = {CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790}.201.
2017/05/14 13:51:38.9728514 1816  3672  Handler         * START *   Windows Setup Install
2017/05/14 13:51:38.9728522 1816  3672  Handler         Updates to install = 1
2017/05/14 13:51:38.9826141 1816  3672  Handler         Loaded state. m_dwState now: Setup360_CompatToolPhase1(5)
2017/05/14 13:51:38.9832211 1816  3672  Handler         Starting Windows Setup with command line = C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\31dde1e25bcbfe972aa2306200d63ffb\WindowsUpdateBox.exe" /ClassId 05c10751-48c3-4b65-8f2a-081073f106ee /ReportId {CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790}.201 /PreDownload /Update /ClientId 063d30ca-e35d-49aa-a3d0-cc17b0b6a955 /CorrelationVector oXyNQzVMHEG9Vg/0.3.1.2"
2017/05/14 13:51:38.9832273 1816  3672  Handler         Registering WinSetup COM server as CLSID {05C10751-48C3-4B65-8F2A-081073F106EE} and APPID {AA6BCD57-30F2-439D-888F-EEF1C74C6D2F}
2017/05/14 13:51:38.9849127 1816  3672  Handler         Successfully registered WinSetup COM server as CLSID {05C10751-48C3-4B65-8F2A-081073F106EE}
2017/05/14 13:51:53.0577334 852   1272  DataStore       Service 1BA85A31-F2A0-4C83-B440-0FE21D81E7FC added
2017/05/14 13:51:53.0578493 852   1272  Agent           AddTargetedServiceMapping: 1BA85A31-F2A0-4C83-B440-0FE21D81E7FC -> 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7
2017/05/14 13:51:53.1913051 2400  4604  ComApi          * START *   Init Search ClientId = Dynamic Update
2017/05/14 13:51:53.1913136 2400  4604  ComApi          * START *   Search ClientId = Dynamic Update
2017/05/14 13:51:53.2183930 852   2684  Agent           * START * Queueing Finding updates [CallerId = Dynamic Update  Id = 4]
2017/05/14 13:51:53.2183988 852   2684  Agent           Removing service 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 from sequential scan list
2017/05/14 13:51:53.2184027 852   2684  Agent           Added service 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 to sequential scan list
2017/05/14 13:51:53.2186113 2400  4604  ComApi          Search ClientId = Dynamic Update
2017/05/14 13:51:53.2311811 852   4664  Agent           * END * Queueing Finding updates [CallerId = Dynamic Update  Id = 4]
2017/05/14 13:51:53.2436770 852   4664  Agent           * START * Finding updates CallerId = Dynamic Update  Id = 4
2017/05/14 13:51:53.2436782 852   4664  Agent           Online = Yes; AllowCachedResults = No; Ignore download priority = No
2017/05/14 13:51:53.2436789 852   4664  Agent           Criteria = ( CategoryIDs contains 'e4b04398-adbd-4b69-93b9-477322331cd3' )""
2017/05/14 13:51:53.2436820 852   4664  Agent           ServiceID = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} Third party service
2017/05/14 13:51:53.2436824 852   4664  Agent           Search Scope = {Machine}
2017/05/14 13:51:53.2436855 852   4664  Agent           Caller SID for Applicability: S-1-5-18
2017/05/14 13:51:53.2436859 852   4664  Agent           RegisterService is set
2017/05/14 13:51:53.2629698 852   4664  Misc            Got WSUS Client/Server URL: http://servername:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx""
2017/05/14 13:51:53.5648593 852   4664  ProtocolTalker  ServiceId = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}, Server URL = http://servername:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2017/05/14 13:51:53.5648604 852   4664  ProtocolTalker  OK to reuse existing configuration
2017/05/14 13:51:53.5648639 852   4664  ProtocolTalker  Existing cookie is valid, just use it
2017/05/14 13:51:53.5648646 852   4664  ProtocolTalker  PTInfo: Server requested registration
2017/05/14 13:51:53.5752440 852   4664  WebServices     Auto proxy settings for this web service call.
2017/05/14 13:51:53.6140394 852   4664  ProtocolTalker  ServiceId = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}, Server URL = http://servername:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2017/05/14 13:51:53.6140452 852   4664  ProtocolTalker  OK to reuse existing configuration
2017/05/14 13:51:53.6140490 852   4664  ProtocolTalker  Existing cookie is valid, just use it
2017/05/14 13:51:53.6140498 852   4664  ProtocolTalker  PTInfo: Server requested registration
2017/05/14 13:51:53.6346969 852   4664  ProtocolTalker  SyncUpdates round trips: 1
2017/05/14 13:51:53.6668259 852   4664  ProtocolTalker  ServiceId = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}, Server URL = http://servername:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2017/05/14 13:51:53.6668275 852   4664  ProtocolTalker  OK to reuse existing configuration
2017/05/14 13:51:53.6668302 852   4664  ProtocolTalker  Existing cookie is valid, just use it
2017/05/14 13:51:53.6668309 852   4664  ProtocolTalker  PTInfo: Server requested registration
2017/05/14 13:51:53.6831695 852   4664  Agent           Found 0 updates and 3 categories in search; evaluated appl. rules of 3 out of 3 deployed entities
2017/05/14 13:51:53.7235279 852   4664  Agent           * END * Finding updates CallerId = Dynamic Update  Id = 4
2017/05/14 13:51:53.7536027 2400  4540  ComApi          *RESUMED* Search ClientId = Dynamic Update
2017/05/14 13:51:53.7553943 2400  4540  ComApi          Updates found = 0
2017/05/14 13:51:53.7553951 2400  4540  ComApi          * END *   Search ClientId = Dynamic Update
2017/05/14 13:51:53.8377106 2400  4604  ComApi          ISusInternal:: DisconnectCall failed, hr=8024000C
2017/05/14 13:51:54.1851153 852   2476  DataStore       Service 1BA85A31-F2A0-4C83-B440-0FE21D81E7FC removed
2017/05/14 13:51:54.1851369 852   2476  Agent           RemoveTargetedServiceMapping: 1BA85A31-F2A0-4C83-B440-0FE21D81E7FC -> 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7
2017/05/14 13:53:38.7675880 1816  3672  Handler         Installer completed. Process return code = 0x00000000, result = 0x00000000, callback pending = True
2017/05/14 13:53:38.7676446 1816  3672  Handler         State changed. was: Setup360_CompatToolPhase1(5), now: Setup360_Phase2DownloadRequest(7)
2017/05/14 13:53:38.7681339 1816  3672  Handler         Saved state. m_dwState: Setup360_Phase2DownloadRequest(7)
2017/05/14 13:53:38.7686744 1816  3672  Handler         Exit code = 0x8024200D
2017/05/14 13:53:38.7686752 1816  3672  Handler         * END *   Windows Setup Install
2017/05/14 13:53:38.7776610 852   4336  DownloadManager Install failed because the update {CCDEB1B6-3E0F-4EEF-B67C-BEF6696AF790} was not complete; mark update as not downloaded.
2017/05/14 13:53:38.7854214 852   4336  Handler         Loaded state. m_dwState now: Setup360_Phase2DownloadRequest(7)
2017/05/14 13:53:38.8517582 852   4336  Agent           Installing updates CallerId = UpdateOrchestrator
2017/05/14 13:53:38.8518091 852   4028  ComApi           Install ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
2017/05/14 13:53:38.8518110 852   4028  ComApi          Install call complete (succeeded = 0, succeeded with errors = 0, failed = 1, unaccounted = 0
2017/05/14 13:53:38.8519600 852   4028  ComApi          Reboot required = False
2017/05/14 13:53:38.8519607 852   4028  ComApi          Exit code = 0x00000000; Call error code = 0x80240022
2017/05/14 13:53:38.8519611 852   4028  ComApi          * END *   Install ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same here... did you manage to find a solution - this issue's driving me nuts!!  Downloading and installing the update manually for every PC works... but it's such a waste of bandwidth!

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet, however I haven't had a time to look at the answer posted by cytraveler yet either. I'm hoping to continue working on this problem in September as I'm currently busy with two large projects. I will update this question if I find a solution.

Comment: This might be related to https://serverfault.com/questions/821413/windows-server-2016-cannot-connect-to-wsus-server (note it's not just for when the server is running 2016) / https://serverfault.com/questions/929199/windows10-not-able-to-download-update-from-wsus ...

Answer (score -1):

It seems like Windows really doesn't want to do the updates if the following services are disabled... (maybe from some privacy tweakin tools or advice?)

here I copy the list of services:

Citation:

Follow the instructions below to apply this workaround and hopefully resolve the issue at hand:

In the Search Windows bar, type services.msc and open Services.
Confirm that the following services on the list are set to run Automatic:

TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper

IKE and AuthIP IPsec Keying Modules

Server

Workstation

Automatic Updates OR Windows Update

Background Intelligent Transfer Service

Right-click on the each of these services and open Properties.
Make sure that they are set to Automatic.

After that:

Download the MEDIA CREATION TOOL

When asked, set it to keep apps and data...

then let it run...

after a while you will be back on a working Windows with all recent updates installed!

Comment: Hello @cytraveler you might want to spend some time on this read: https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer I started editing your answer but I gave up because it’s too much job! ;)

Comment: Copy and pasted from https://windowsreport.com/media-creation-tool-creators-update/ but without the screenshots