# Windows10 not able to download update from WSUS

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10, wsus, windows-update

W10 client Updatelogs:

```
2018. 09. 03 14:37:18.8871861 3044  3312  Misc            Got WSUS Client/Server URL: http://xxx-wsus.xxxx.local:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx""
2018. 09. 03 14:37:18.8876853 3044  3312  ProtocolTalker  OK to reuse existing configuration
2018. 09. 03 14:37:18.8876893 3044  3312  ProtocolTalker  Existing cookie is valid, just use it
2018. 09. 03 14:37:18.8876916 3044  3312  ProtocolTalker  PTInfo: Server requested registration
2018. 09. 03 14:37:18.9196805 3044  3312  Misc            Got WSUS Reporting URL: http://xxx-wsus.xxxx.local:8530/ReportingWebService/ReportingWebService.asmx""
2018. 09. 03 14:37:18.9206512 3044  3312  WebServices     Auto proxy settings for this web service call.
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9662759 3044  4728  ComApi          * START *   Download ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9662773 3044  4728  ComApi          Flags: 0; Download priority: 2; Network Cost Policy: 0
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9662779 3044  4728  ComApi          Updates in request: 1
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9663077 3044  4728  ComApi          ServiceID = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} Managed
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9676052 3044  4728  ComApi          *QUEUED* Download ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9678359 3044  4728  ComApi          * START *   Download ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9678369 3044  4728  ComApi          Flags: 0; Download priority: 2; Network Cost Policy: 0
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9678376 3044  4728  ComApi          Updates in request: 1
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9678585 3044  4728  ComApi          ServiceID = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} Managed
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9680439 3044  3312  Shared          Effective power state: AC
1601. 01. 01 01:00:00.0000000 3044  3312                  Unknown( 37): GUID=16b00d31-8e89-3c95-8c8e-5dbc3ff7a198 (No Format Information found).
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9687401 3044  4728  ComApi          *QUEUED* Download ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9689745 3044  4728  ComApi          * START *   Download ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9689758 3044  4728  ComApi          Flags: 0; Download priority: 2; Network Cost Policy: 0
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9689762 3044  4728  ComApi          Updates in request: 1
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9689914 3044  4728  ComApi          ServiceID = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} Managed
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9699214 3044  4728  ComApi          *QUEUED* Download ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
1601. 01. 01 01:00:00.0000000 3044  3312                  Unknown( 196): GUID=d1c97d0d-9e32-3972-1423-e056c370718e (No Format Information found).
1601. 01. 01 01:00:00.0000000 3044  3312                  Unknown( 197): GUID=d1c97d0d-9e32-3972-1423-e056c370718e (No Format Information found).
1601. 01. 01 01:00:00.0000000 3044  3312                  Unknown( 198): GUID=d1c97d0d-9e32-3972-1423-e056c370718e (No Format Information found).
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9741472 3044  3312  Agent             Title = 2018??05 Biztons??gi friss??t??s a(z) Windows 10 Version 1607 rendszerhez k??sz??lt Adobe Flash Player programhoz, x64-alap?? rendszerek eset??n (KB4103729)
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9741521 3044  3312  Agent             UpdateId = F3593C49-0494-45AB-BCF5-376B262FF61C.201
2018. 09. 03 14:37:27.9741525 3044  3312  Agent               Bundles 1 updates:
```

wsus/c$/Programfiles/UpdateServices/LogFiles/SoftwareDistribution.log:

```
2018-09-03 23:30:18.467 UTC Info    WsusService.8   SusEventDispatcher.TriggerEvent TriggerEvent called for NotificationEventName: CatalogSyncAgent, EventInfo: 
2018-09-03 23:30:18.467 UTC Info    WsusService.14  ThreadEntry ThreadHelper.ThreadStart
2018-09-03 23:30:18.467 UTC Info    WsusService.14  SusEventDispatcher.DispatchManagerWorkerThreadProc  DispatchManager Worker Thread Processing NotificationEvent: CatalogSyncAgent
2018-09-03 23:30:18.483 UTC Info    WsusService.8   SusEventDispatcher.TriggerEvent TriggerEvent called for NotificationEventName: ConfigurationChange, EventInfo: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:18.483 UTC Info    WsusService.29  ThreadEntry ThreadHelper.ThreadStart
2018-09-03 23:30:18.483 UTC Info    WsusService.29  SusEventDispatcher.DispatchManagerWorkerThreadProc  DispatchManager Worker Thread Processing NotificationEvent: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:18.514 UTC Info    WsusService.14  CatalogSyncAgentCore.SyncUpdatesOutsideSubscription sync'ing 0 updates with catalog site flag
2018-09-03 23:30:18.514 UTC Info    WsusService.14  EventLogEventReporter.ReportEvent   EventId=381,Type=Information,Category=Synchronization,Message=A scheduled synchronization was started.
2018-09-03 23:30:18.514 UTC Info    WsusService.29  ServerCertificxxxalidator.ConfigChangedHandler  Update server configuration has changed. Sync against MU: True
2018-09-03 23:30:18.530 UTC Info    WsusService.14  AuthorizationManager.GetUpstreamServerUriHeader Found config says USS is MU site
2018-09-03 23:30:18.545 UTC Info    WsusService.14  ServerSyncLib.GetWebServiceProxyInternal    Found config says USS is MU site
2018-09-03 23:30:18.545 UTC Info    WsusService.14  AuthorizationManager.GetUpstreamServerUriHeader Found config says USS is MU site
2018-09-03 23:30:18.545 UTC Info    WsusService.14  CatalogSyncAgentCore.ExecuteSyncProtocol    Server ID is dfe704eb-443b-45c4-9b5a-1cd1c98e325d
2018-09-03 23:30:18.889 UTC Info    w3wp.24 SusEventDispatcher.TriggerEvent TriggerEvent called for NotificationEventName: ConfigurationChange, EventInfo: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:18.889 UTC Info    w3wp.17 SusEventDispatcher.TriggerEvent TriggerEvent called for NotificationEventName: ConfigurationChange, EventInfo: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:18.889 UTC Info    w3wp.46 SusEventDispatcher.DispatchManagerWorkerThreadProc  DispatchManager Worker Thread Processing NotificationEvent: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:18.889 UTC Info    w3wp.46 ChangeNotificationDispatcher.InternalEventHandler   Get event ConfigurationChange from dispatchmanager
2018-09-03 23:30:18.889 UTC Info    w3wp.23 Client.OnConfigurationChange    Creating a new ClientImplementation because the DB configuration changed
2018-09-03 23:30:18.889 UTC Info    w3wp.23 ClientImplementation..ctor  Initializing ClientWebService ProcessID = 2044, Process Start Time = 2018.09.03. 14:32:07, Product Version = 6.3.9600.18838
2018-09-03 23:30:18.889 UTC Info    w3wp.37 ThreadEntry ThreadHelper.ThreadStart
2018-09-03 23:30:18.889 UTC Info    w3wp.37 SusEventDispatcher.DispatchManagerWorkerThreadProc  DispatchManager Worker Thread Processing NotificationEvent: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:18.889 UTC Info    w3wp.37 RevisionIdCacheChangeNotificationDispatcher.InternalEventHandler    Get event ConfigurationChange from dispatchmanager
2018-09-03 23:30:18.905 UTC Info    w3wp.23 AuthorizationManager.GetUpstreamServerUriHeader Found config says USS is MU site
2018-09-03 23:30:18.936 UTC Info    WsusService.14  SusService.ValidateServerCertificate    CheckValidationResult Succeeds: CertOK
2018-09-03 23:30:18.936 UTC Info    WsusService.14  ServerCertificxxxalidator.IsHostAllowedException    Requested host: fe2.update.microsoft.com
2018-09-03 23:30:18.952 UTC Info    WsusService.14  ServerCertificxxxalidator.VerifyServerCertificate   SSL validation succeeded.
2018-09-03 23:30:19.905 UTC Info    WsusService.14  CatalogSyncAgentCore.SyncConfigUpdatesFromUSS   Category Sync: Filter: <filter SyncAnchor="42786472,2018-09-03 17:30:20.833" GetConfig="1"></filter>
2018-09-03 23:30:20.155 UTC Info    WsusService.14  CatalogSyncAgentCore.SyncConfigUpdatesFromUSS   Need 0 config updates, 0 are new
2018-09-03 23:30:20.202 UTC Info    WsusService.14  CatalogSyncAgentCore.SyncConfigUpdatesFromUSS   Category Sync: New Config Anchor: 42787783,2018-09-03 23:30:19.933
2018-09-03 23:30:20.202 UTC Info    WsusService.14  CatalogSyncAgentCore.ExecuteSyncProtocol    Catalog Sync: Filter: <filter SyncAnchor="42759301,2018-08-30 17:29:45.012"><CategoryList><category delta="1" value="84f5f325-30d7-41c4-81d1-87a0e6535b66" /><category delta="1" value="8508af86-b85e-450f-a518-3b6f8f204eea" /><category delta="1" value="8b4e84f6-595f-41ed-854f-4ca886e317a5" /><category delta="1" value="bfe5b177-a086-47a0-b102-097e4fa1f807" /><category delta="1" value="caab596c-64f2-4aa9-bbe3-784c6e2ccf9c" /><category delta="1" value="d2085b71-5f1f-43a9-880d-ed159016d5c6" /><category delta="1" value="d31bd4c3-d872-41c9-a2e7-231f372588cb" /><category delta="1" value="f3c2263d-b256-4c49-a246-973c0e366449" /><category delta="1" value="f76b7f51-b762-4fd0-a35c-e04f582acf42" /></CategoryList><UCList><updateclassification delta="1" value="e6cf1350-c01b-414d-a61f-263d14d133b4" /><updateclassification delta="1" value="0fa1201d-4330-4fa8-8ae9-b877473b6441" /><updateclassification delta="1" value="e0789628-ce08-4437-be74-2495b842f43b" /><updateclassification delta="1" value="3689bdc8-b205-4af4-8d4a-a63924c5e9d5" /></UCList><languageList><language delta="1" value="1033" /><language delta="1" value="1038" /></languageList></filter>
2018-09-03 23:30:20.437 UTC Info    WsusService.14  CatalogSyncAgentCore.ExecuteSyncProtocol    Catalog Sync: New Anchor: 42787783,2018-09-03 23:30:20.464
2018-09-03 23:30:20.437 UTC Info    WsusService.14  CatalogSyncAgentCore.ExecuteSyncProtocol    Need 0 updates, 0 are new
2018-09-03 23:30:20.437 UTC Info    WsusService.14  CatalogSyncAgentCore.ExecuteSyncProtocol    Total actually inserted updates: 0
2018-09-03 23:30:20.499 UTC Change  WsusService.14  AdminDataAccess.ExecuteSPResumeAllDownloads Downloading retried
2018-09-03 23:30:20.499 UTC Info    WsusService.14  CatalogSyncAgentCore.UpdateSyncResultAndGenerateReportingEvent  CatalogSyncThreadProcess: report subscription succeeded
2018-09-03 23:30:20.499 UTC Info    WsusService.14  EventLogEventReporter.ReportEvent   EventId=384,Type=Information,Category=Synchronization,Message=Synchronization completed successfully.
2018-09-03 23:30:20.515 UTC Info    w3wp.25 SusEventDispatcher.TriggerEvent TriggerEvent called for NotificationEventName: ConfigurationChange, EventInfo: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:20.515 UTC Info    w3wp.13 SusEventDispatcher.TriggerEvent TriggerEvent called for NotificationEventName: ConfigurationChange, EventInfo: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:20.515 UTC Info    w3wp.41 ThreadEntry ThreadHelper.ThreadStart
2018-09-03 23:30:20.515 UTC Info    w3wp.41 SusEventDispatcher.DispatchManagerWorkerThreadProc  DispatchManager Worker Thread Processing NotificationEvent: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:20.515 UTC Info    w3wp.16 ThreadEntry ThreadHelper.ThreadStart
2018-09-03 23:30:20.515 UTC Info    w3wp.16 SusEventDispatcher.DispatchManagerWorkerThreadProc  DispatchManager Worker Thread Processing NotificationEvent: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:20.515 UTC Info    w3wp.12 SusEventDispatcher.RegisterEventHandler RegisterEventHandler called for NotificationEventName: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:20.546 UTC Info    w3wp.41 AuthorizationManager.GetUpstreamServerUriHeader Found config says USS is MU site
2018-09-03 23:30:20.546 UTC Info    w3wp.12 AuthorizationManager.GetUpstreamServerUriHeader Found config says USS is MU site
2018-09-03 23:30:20.546 UTC Info    w3wp.12 SusEventDispatcher.RegisterEventHandler RegisterEventHandler called for NotificationEventName: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:20.562 UTC Info    w3wp.12 AuthorizationManager.GetUpstreamServerUriHeader Found config says USS is MU site
2018-09-03 23:30:20.562 UTC Info    WsusService.35  ThreadEntry ThreadHelper.ThreadStart
2018-09-03 23:30:20.562 UTC Info    WsusService.35  CatalogSyncAgent.WaitUntilSyncFinishedOrCancelled   Agent signalled done.
2018-09-03 23:30:20.562 UTC Info    WsusService.35  CatalogSyncAgent.SetSubscriptionStateWithRetry  Firing event SyncFinish...
2018-09-03 23:30:20.562 UTC Info    WsusService.35  CatalogSyncAgent.WakeUpWorkerThreadProc Found no more jobs. CatalogSyncAgent quits but will run rollup before terminating ...
2018-09-03 23:30:20.562 UTC Info    WsusService.35  CatalogSyncAgent.UpdateServerHealthStatusBasedOnError   ServerHealth: Updating Server Health for Component: CatalogSyncAgent, Marking as Not Running
2018-09-03 23:30:23.532 UTC Info    WsusService.8   SusEventDispatcher.TriggerEvent TriggerEvent called for NotificationEventName: ContentSyncAgent, EventInfo: 
2018-09-03 23:30:23.532 UTC Info    WsusService.8   SusEventDispatcher.TriggerEvent TriggerEvent called for NotificationEventName: RollupAgent, EventInfo: 
2018-09-03 23:30:23.532 UTC Info    WsusService.8   SusEventDispatcher.TriggerEvent TriggerEvent called for NotificationEventName: EmailNotificationAgent, EventInfo: 
2018-09-03 23:30:23.532 UTC Info    WsusService.3   ThreadEntry ThreadHelper.ThreadStart
2018-09-03 23:30:23.532 UTC Info    WsusService.3   SusEventDispatcher.DispatchManagerWorkerThreadProc  DispatchManager Worker Thread Processing NotificationEvent: ContentSyncAgent
2018-09-03 23:30:23.532 UTC Info    WsusService.38  SusEventDispatcher.RegisterEventHandler RegisterEventHandler called for NotificationEventName: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:23.532 UTC Info    WsusService.38  EventLogEventReporter.ReportEvent   EventId=361,Type=Information,Category=Synchronization,Message=Content synchronization started.
2018-09-03 23:30:23.532 UTC Info    WsusService.3   SusEventDispatcher.DispatchManagerWorkerThreadProc  DispatchManager Worker Thread Processing NotificationEvent: RollupAgent
2018-09-03 23:30:23.532 UTC Info    WsusService.3   SusEventDispatcher.DispatchManagerWorkerThreadProc  DispatchManager Worker Thread Processing NotificationEvent: EmailNotificationAgent
2018-09-03 23:30:23.532 UTC Info    WsusService.41  ThreadEntry ThreadHelper.ThreadStart
2018-09-03 23:30:23.532 UTC Info    WsusService.41  EmailNotificationAgent.WakeUpWorkerThreadProc   Email Notification Agent Starting
2018-09-03 23:30:23.547 UTC Info    WsusService.8   SusEventDispatcher.TriggerEvent TriggerEvent called for NotificationEventName: ConfigurationChange, EventInfo: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:23.547 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.WakeUpWorkerThreadProc ServerHealth: Updating Server Health for Component: ContentSyncAgent Running, Marking as Running
2018-09-03 23:30:23.547 UTC Info    WsusService.24  SusEventDispatcher.DispatchManagerWorkerThreadProc  DispatchManager Worker Thread Processing NotificationEvent: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:23.594 UTC Info    WsusService.24  ServerCertificxxxalidator.ConfigChangedHandler  Update server configuration has changed. Sync against MU: True
2018-09-03 23:30:23.813 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.WakeUpWorkerThreadProc Processing Item: 2f67e848-2242-4d25-8383-49f5eee3afcb, State: 10
2018-09-03 23:30:23.844 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.Download   Item: 2f67e848-2242-4d25-8383-49f5eee3afcb has been submitted to BITS for Download
2018-09-03 23:30:23.891 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.WakeUpWorkerThreadProc Processing Item: 9dec000a-31c0-496b-b0d1-f9e96f7f5ec3, State: 10
2018-09-03 23:30:23.891 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.Download   Item: 9dec000a-31c0-496b-b0d1-f9e96f7f5ec3 has been submitted to BITS for Download
2018-09-03 23:30:23.907 UTC Info    w3wp.24 SusEventDispatcher.TriggerEvent TriggerEvent called for NotificationEventName: ConfigurationChange, EventInfo: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:23.922 UTC Info    w3wp.17 SusEventDispatcher.TriggerEvent TriggerEvent called for NotificationEventName: ConfigurationChange, EventInfo: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:23.922 UTC Info    w3wp.3  ThreadEntry ThreadHelper.ThreadStart
2018-09-03 23:30:23.922 UTC Info    w3wp.3  SusEventDispatcher.DispatchManagerWorkerThreadProc  DispatchManager Worker Thread Processing NotificationEvent: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:23.922 UTC Info    w3wp.3  ChangeNotificationDispatcher.InternalEventHandler   Get event ConfigurationChange from dispatchmanager
2018-09-03 23:30:23.922 UTC Info    w3wp.23 Client.OnConfigurationChange    Creating a new ClientImplementation because the DB configuration changed
2018-09-03 23:30:23.922 UTC Info    w3wp.23 ClientImplementation..ctor  Initializing ClientWebService ProcessID = 2044, Process Start Time = 2018.09.03. 14:32:07, Product Version = 6.3.9600.18838
2018-09-03 23:30:23.922 UTC Info    WsusService.41  EmailNotificationAgent.WakeUpWorkerThreadProc   Empty email for notification type NewSync; email notification ignored
2018-09-03 23:30:23.922 UTC Info    w3wp.53 ThreadEntry ThreadHelper.ThreadStart
2018-09-03 23:30:23.922 UTC Info    w3wp.53 SusEventDispatcher.DispatchManagerWorkerThreadProc  DispatchManager Worker Thread Processing NotificationEvent: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:23.922 UTC Info    w3wp.53 RevisionIdCacheChangeNotificationDispatcher.InternalEventHandler    Get event ConfigurationChange from dispatchmanager
2018-09-03 23:30:23.938 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.WakeUpWorkerThreadProc ContentSyncAgent found no more Jobs, going to Sleep for BITS Notifications
2018-09-03 23:30:23.938 UTC Info    w3wp.23 AuthorizationManager.GetUpstreamServerUriHeader Found config says USS is MU site
2018-09-03 23:30:23.938 UTC Info    WsusService.41  EmailNotificationAgent.WakeUpWorkerThreadProc   Email Notification Agent Finished
2018-09-03 23:30:23.954 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.WakeUpWorkerThreadProc ContentSyncAgent found no more Jobs, going to Sleep for BITS Notifications
2018-09-03 23:30:24.657 UTC Info    WsusService.43  ThreadEntry ThreadHelper.ThreadStart
2018-09-03 23:30:24.657 UTC Info    WsusService.43  RollupEventReporter.BuildReportingServiceUrl    Found config says USS is MU site
2018-09-03 23:30:24.720 UTC Info    WsusService.43  MicrosoftUpdateRollup.ReportEvents  Rolling up 4 events.
2018-09-03 23:30:25.282 UTC Info    WsusService.43  SusService.ValidateServerCertificate    CheckValidationResult Succeeds: CertOK
2018-09-03 23:30:25.282 UTC Info    WsusService.43  ServerCertificxxxalidator.IsHostAllowedException    Requested host: statsfe2.update.microsoft.com
2018-09-03 23:30:25.282 UTC Info    WsusService.43  ServerCertificxxxalidator.IsHostAllowedException    Ignoring SSL validation for a well-know host.
2018-09-03 23:30:25.532 UTC Info    w3wp.25 SusEventDispatcher.TriggerEvent TriggerEvent called for NotificationEventName: ConfigurationChange, EventInfo: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:25.532 UTC Info    w3wp.13 SusEventDispatcher.TriggerEvent TriggerEvent called for NotificationEventName: ConfigurationChange, EventInfo: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:25.532 UTC Info    w3wp.34 SusEventDispatcher.DispatchManagerWorkerThreadProc  DispatchManager Worker Thread Processing NotificationEvent: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:25.532 UTC Info    w3wp.33 ThreadEntry ThreadHelper.ThreadStart
2018-09-03 23:30:25.532 UTC Info    w3wp.33 SusEventDispatcher.DispatchManagerWorkerThreadProc  DispatchManager Worker Thread Processing NotificationEvent: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:25.532 UTC Info    w3wp.12 SusEventDispatcher.RegisterEventHandler RegisterEventHandler called for NotificationEventName: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:25.548 UTC Info    w3wp.12 AuthorizationManager.GetUpstreamServerUriHeader Found config says USS is MU site
2018-09-03 23:30:25.564 UTC Info    w3wp.34 AuthorizationManager.GetUpstreamServerUriHeader Found config says USS is MU site
2018-09-03 23:30:25.564 UTC Info    w3wp.12 SusEventDispatcher.RegisterEventHandler RegisterEventHandler called for NotificationEventName: ConfigurationChange
2018-09-03 23:30:25.564 UTC Info    w3wp.12 AuthorizationManager.GetUpstreamServerUriHeader Found config says USS is MU site
2018-09-03 23:30:25.642 UTC Info    WsusService.43  RollupEventReader.SetLastRollupComplete Finished Rollup.  Setting time anchor in local DB as 2018.09.03. 23:30:20
2018-09-03 23:30:33.723 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.ProcessBITSNotificationQueue   ContentSyncAgent recieved Transferred Event for Item: 2f67e848-2242-4d25-8383-49f5eee3afcb
2018-09-03 23:30:33.723 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.ContentSyncSPFireStateMachineEvent ContentSyncAgent firing Event: FileDownloaded for Item: 2f67e848-2242-4d25-8383-49f5eee3afcb
2018-09-03 23:30:33.739 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.VerifyCRC  filelocalpath is c:\wsusDatastore\WsusContent\23\F8CC3C3282C9D0EFF5C59AE004BD468D037A0B23.cab, additionalHash is F661FB69CA3508CD7A689BFDC98A3E70F8F0552AD3E824FAEC28FC918EB29414
2018-09-03 23:30:33.848 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.VerifyCRC  calculated sha1 hash is F8CC3C3282C9D0EFF5C59AE004BD468D037A0B23
2018-09-03 23:30:33.848 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.VerifyCRC  matched sha1 hash
2018-09-03 23:30:34.051 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.VerifyCRC  calculated sha2 sha256 hash is F661FB69CA3508CD7A689BFDC98A3E70F8F0552AD3E824FAEC28FC918EB29414
2018-09-03 23:30:34.489 UTC Info    WsusService.38  CabUtilities.CheckCertificateSignature  File cert verification failed for c:\wsusDatastore\WsusContent\23\F8CC3C3282C9D0EFF5C59AE004BD468D037A0B23.cab with 2148204801
2018-09-03 23:30:34.489 UTC Warning WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.ProcessBITSNotificationQueue   Invalid file deleted: c:\wsusDatastore\WsusContent\23\F8CC3C3282C9D0EFF5C59AE004BD468D037A0B23.cab
2018-09-03 23:30:34.505 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.ContentSyncSPFireStateMachineEvent ContentSyncAgent firing Event: FileVerificationFailed for Item: 2f67e848-2242-4d25-8383-49f5eee3afcb
2018-09-03 23:30:34.505 UTC Info    WsusService.38  EventLogEventReporter.ReportEvent   EventId=364,Type=Error,Category=Synchronization,Message=Content file download failed.
Reason: File cert verification failure. 
Source File: /c/msdownload/update/software/secu/2017/06/windows10.0-kb4022730-x64_f8cc3c3282c9d0eff5c59ae004bd468d037a0b23.cab 
Destination File: c:\wsusDatastore\WsusContent\23\F8CC3C3282C9D0EFF5C59AE004BD468D037A0B23.cab
2018-09-03 23:30:34.536 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.ProcessBITSNotificationQueue   ContentSyncAgent recieved Transferred Event for Item: 9dec000a-31c0-496b-b0d1-f9e96f7f5ec3
2018-09-03 23:30:34.536 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.ContentSyncSPFireStateMachineEvent ContentSyncAgent firing Event: FileDownloaded for Item: 9dec000a-31c0-496b-b0d1-f9e96f7f5ec3
2018-09-03 23:30:34.567 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.VerifyCRC  filelocalpath is c:\wsusDatastore\WsusContent\F4\749A5A7AF3AC36A1FF014171F2B21EB38FC224F4.cab, additionalHash is 2B3B3A8B7C848064AB0703ECC093DAB57888D19AEB74FC2ECAF517EA857C8A19
2018-09-03 23:30:34.614 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.VerifyCRC  calculated sha1 hash is 749A5A7AF3AC36A1FF014171F2B21EB38FC224F4
2018-09-03 23:30:34.614 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.VerifyCRC  matched sha1 hash
2018-09-03 23:30:34.739 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.VerifyCRC  calculated sha2 sha256 hash is 2B3B3A8B7C848064AB0703ECC093DAB57888D19AEB74FC2ECAF517EA857C8A19
2018-09-03 23:30:34.864 UTC Info    WsusService.38  CabUtilities.CheckCertificateSignature  File cert verification failed for c:\wsusDatastore\WsusContent\F4\749A5A7AF3AC36A1FF014171F2B21EB38FC224F4.cab with 2148204801
2018-09-03 23:30:34.864 UTC Warning WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.ProcessBITSNotificationQueue   Invalid file deleted: c:\wsusDatastore\WsusContent\F4\749A5A7AF3AC36A1FF014171F2B21EB38FC224F4.cab
2018-09-03 23:30:34.864 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.ContentSyncSPFireStateMachineEvent ContentSyncAgent firing Event: FileVerificationFailed for Item: 9dec000a-31c0-496b-b0d1-f9e96f7f5ec3
2018-09-03 23:30:34.880 UTC Info    WsusService.38  EventLogEventReporter.ReportEvent   EventId=364,Type=Error,Category=Synchronization,Message=Content file download failed.
Reason: File cert verification failure. 
Source File: /c/msdownload/update/software/secu/2017/06/windows10.0-kb4022730-x86_749a5a7af3ac36a1ff014171f2b21eb38fc224f4.cab 
Destination File: c:\wsusDatastore\WsusContent\F4\749A5A7AF3AC36A1FF014171F2B21EB38FC224F4.cab
2018-09-03 23:30:34.880 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.WakeUpWorkerThreadProc ContentSyncAgent found no more Jobs, thread exitting
2018-09-03 23:30:35.067 UTC Info    WsusService.38  EventLogEventReporter.ReportEvent   EventId=363,Type=Information,Category=Synchronization,Message=Content synchronization succeeded.
2018-09-03 23:30:35.067 UTC Info    WsusService.38  ContentSyncAgent.WakeUpWorkerThreadProc ServerHealth: Updating Server Health for Component: ContentSyncAgent, Marking as Not Running
2018-09-03 23:30:53.949 UTC Info    w3wp.32 ThreadEntry TimerQueue.FireNextTimers
2018-09-03 23:30:53.949 UTC Info    w3wp.32 ServerImplementation.UpdateCache    Database change occured; check if we need to update cache. 
2018-09-04 04:48:53.866 UTC Warning w3wp.60 SoapUtilities.CreateException   ThrowException: actor = http://xxx-wsus.xxxx.local:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx, ID=af9d8b55-f59d-473f-a3c6-7118bcd55c28, ErrorCode=ServerChanged, Message=Server rolled back since last call to GetCookie, Client=e8138a18-7f4f-47a0-96ee-ace469330baf
2018-09-04 04:49:45.837 UTC Warning w3wp.59 SoapUtilities.CreateException   ThrowException: actor = http://xxx-wsus.xxxx.local:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx, ID=328b65de-b548-4b6e-82e9-8dff228e622c, ErrorCode=ServerChanged, Message=Server rolled back since last call to GetCookie, Client=03126354-ea92-480c-8e80-80d8e689de68
2018-09-04 04:50:36.416 UTC Warning w3wp.36 SoapUtilities.CreateException   ThrowException: actor = http://xxx-wsus.xxxx.local:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx, ID=1368ac21-a72c-4a7b-9b72-3d539df558d7, ErrorCode=ServerChanged, Message=Server rolled back since last call to GetCookie, Client=12aa25c6-8af3-4500-acc3-08acf0008846
2018-09-04 04:51:59.465 UTC Warning w3wp.58 SoapUtilities.CreateException   ThrowException: actor = http://xxx-wsus.xxxx.local:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx, ID=9bea949e-b14b-41a4-8ae2-ebedca5d8f94, ErrorCode=ServerChanged, Message=Server rolled back since last call to GetCookie, Client=833d3ad7-ad15-4121-b450-8342f1613bbe
2018-09-04 04:59:59.494 UTC Warning w3wp.36 SoapUtilities.CreateException   ThrowException: actor = http://xxx-wsus.xxxx.local:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx, ID=ec2d963f-d89b-4de0-bb2d-730e44b3ac8b, ErrorCode=ServerChanged, Message=Server rolled back since last call to GetCookie, Client=d332da3d-85ea-4daa-b05d-b3657a8bf4a5
2018-09-04 05:00:52.980 UTC Warning w3wp.43 SoapUtilities.CreateException   ThrowException: actor = http://xxx-wsus.xxxx.local:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx, ID=3522409c-9bfa-48bd-94a9-c675e59b0abf, ErrorCode=ServerChanged, Message=Server rolled back since last call to GetCookie, Client=9e069acc-57eb-4da1-b36c-c72ebc598d13
2018-09-04 05:03:37.849 UTC Warning w3wp.58 SoapUtilities.CreateException   ThrowException: actor = http://xxx-wsus.xxxx.local:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx, ID=2e02f18f-d358-4a98-9afe-d746680f6f36, ErrorCode=ServerChanged, Message=Server rolled back since last call to GetCookie, Client=f5f46c9e-04b3-440d-9278-ee8115a01ca5
2018-09-04 05:04:47.684 UTC Warning w3wp.54 SoapUtilities.CreateException   ThrowException: actor = http://xxx-wsus.xxxx.local:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx, ID=496dd332-93d7-47b6-bb3c-15cbc8a77cee, ErrorCode=ServerChanged, Message=Server rolled back since last call to GetCookie, Client=363adb8b-aeea-4d59-8c2e-7aa1e1fbacfe
2018-09-04 05:07:12.038 UTC Info    WsusService.4   ThreadEntry ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch
2018-09-04 05:07:12.038 UTC Info    WsusService.4   SusService.OnStop   EventId=502,Type=Information,Category=WsusService,Message=Update Services Service Has Stopped
2018-09-04 05:09:26.145 UTC Warning w3wp.20 DBConnection.OnReceivingInfoMessage  The join order has been enforced because a local join hint is used.
2018-09-04 05:10:25.935 UTC Warning w3wp.15 SoapUtilities.CreateException   ThrowException: actor = http://xxx-wsus.xxxx.local:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx, ID=29ee4a1a-e018-4046-bace-98b9c3f847ec, ErrorCode=ServerChanged, Message=Server rolled back since last call to GetCookie, Client=2ba9c936-569a-4861-b42b-51089b64ee9f
2018-09-04 05:12:27.298 UTC Warning w3wp.43 SoapUtilities.CreateException   ThrowException: actor = http://xxx-wsus.xxxx.local:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx, ID=eb8d0613-ac4e-43f9-8c3e-0f7b54e39281, ErrorCode=ServerChanged, Message=Server rolled back since last call to GetCookie, Client=c9184def-f323-4607-919d-b9c0c3372aad
```

WSUS running on SRV2012R2, up - to date - installed KB3159706, KB3095113 as the technet wrote it - in Windwos7 client everything is ok, the updates downloaded from the wsus server, and installed correctly. When I connected to domain the new W10 client, everything ok, gets the correct GPO - in regedit the update server is the wsus server-. We use proxy, also the clients not able to download updates from the Windows Servers - blocked by firewall -.

Comment: Try: 1. Stopping Windows Update Service, 2. Stopping Update Orchestrator Service, 3. Deleting all contents inside C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution folder, 4. Restarting the above two services. 5. Again, perform a fresh "Check for Updates". See if it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: Thanks for your help! As Victor Wong write, it was an update problem. If i install ed windows10.0-kb3189866 the update will okay from WSUS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following steps to reset windows update related services and folder.

First launch CMD as administrator and run the following to stop Windows update related services.

```
net stop bits
net stop wuauserv
net stop appidvsvc
net stop cryptsvc
```

Then rename the existing update folder to force windows update to recreate the update folder and restart the downloads.

```
ren %systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution BuggySoftwareDistribution
ren %systemroot%\system32\catroot2 Buggycatroot2
```

Finally restart the stopped services.

```
net start bits
net start wuauserv
net start appidsvc
net start cryptsvc
```

Hopefully windows update is now working fine.

Comment: Tried, but the problem is still the same. I expands the error logs, also add some information what I tried. Thanks for the help!

Comment: From your client log I see that it is using Windows 10 1607 release which has a known issue with windows update.

Can you manually install this cumulative update KB3193494 then restart to see if that fix the issue?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3193494/cumulative-update-for-windows-10-version-1607-september-20-2016

Comment: It's W10 Enterprise LTSB 1607 release.

Comment: I made a typo on the comment, I meant 1607 indeed (Now fixed).

Comment: You're the man! Many thanks for the help. I need some search wich update replace KB3193494, finally find it. The required update is: windows10.0-kb3189866

Comment: Happy to help!. If this solved your issue please mark this as the answer.