# Windows 2019 WSUS Error 0x8000ffff when pushing out Windows 10 Upgrades

Tags: iis, windows-update, wsus, windows-server-2019, mmc

I've had this error on 3 separate Windows 2019 servers I've tried to install Windows Server update Services (WSUS) on; It's worked fine on every Windows 2016 server I've configured, so I'm assuming I'm getting something wrong, or something's changed in 2019, but I've had no luck finding it:

Configuring WSUS on 2019 using the defaults leads to a WSUS Server that can push out all normal security updates to Windows 10 Clients, but fails on the upgrades category with Error 0x8000ffff.

This was a fairly common issue on the 2012/2012R2 version of WSUS to do with Upgrades being Encrypted. The fix was [Add the ESD MIME Type into IIS](https://rdr-it.com/en/troubleshooting/wsus-fix-the-problem-of-downloading-windows-10-updates/)

Out of the Box, Rather than have no ESD MIME Type, 2019 WSUS Adds `Application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed`. I've tried leaving it that tried changing it to `application/octet-stream`, but on all three servers, Clients refuse to Upgrade to 1903 with error 0x8000ffff:

[image: error 0x8000fff]

I've tried googling around this, but most things I've found point to deleted [KB3194588](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3194588), or seems to be specific to [Windows 2012](https://serverfault.com/questions/850038/wsus-windows-10-updates-not-working)

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I don't mind completely wiping the WSUS Installation on the current 2019 server I'm working on, if that's a quicker way to get upgrade packages working.

Comment: why not check IIS log files? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 You might find the actual log entries for WSUS requests and see if any hints are there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Lex, i'll get on that tomorrow.